# How to resolve the issue on using cookieParser in NestJS

Tags: typescript, cookies, nestjs, hosting, vercel

So happy to ask you here.

I am working on building backend using NestJS, which is a Node.js framework.
Everything works very well but I got some issues when hosting.

Actually I create a new NestJS project and just added a few lines of code in **main.ts** as following.

**main.ts**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'; // This is what I found issue with.

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { bodyParser: true });
  app.enableCors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: [
      'http://localhost:3000',
      'http://localhost:3001',
    ],
  });
  app.use(cookieParser());
  await app.listen(3002);
}
bootstrap();
```

The issue which has almost killed me is,
when importing cookieParser from 'cookie-parser' module, NestJS documentation says I need to use **import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'**.
And this works locally.
But when I use **vercel** to host for test, it says **This Serverless Function has crashed.**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5t0X.png)

So to fix this, I tried to replace the import statement into following codes.
**import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'**
And it's working on **vercel** but not working locally.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E75Ni.png)

And I tried to test this code on **Bluehost**, which is my product server.
And it works with **import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'** there.

I don't understand this and am not sure which one is definitely right.
Would you please let me know what should I do to work on both of locally, in test hosting, in product hosting?

Comment: read this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#esModuleInterop

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "esModuleInterop": true,
}
```

And change your import from

```
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
```

to

```
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
```

Comment: It's working locally but not on Vercel.
It still says `This serverless function has crashed!`.

Comment: Strange, it worked great for me, can you show me your tsconfig? Maybe "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" is a problem